# matlab image processing 3d

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i have 100 b&w image of smthing.the probllem is i want to scan each image in 0&1 formatin mby n format and then place each image to one over one and again scan and save them in mbynby100 form.
how i do this and from where i should start
_jaysean

Comment: I suggest you start by rewriting your question into a form that is easy for us to read and to understand. F u dnt we cnt hlp. + tell us wot u have did allreddy.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is vague and hard to understand, but my guess is that you want to take 100 M-by-N [grayscale intensity images](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f2-10709.html#f2-175), threshold them to create [logical matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-97022.html) (i.e. containing zeroes and ones), then put them together into one M-by-N-by-100 matrix. You can do the thresholding by simply picking a threshold value yourself, like `0.5`, and applying it to an image `A` as follows:

```
B = A > 0.5;
```

The matrix `B` will now be an M-by-N logical matrix with ones where `A` is greater than `0.5` and zeroes where `A` is less than or equal to `0.5`.

If you have the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/), you could instead use the function [GRAYTHRESH](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/graythresh.html) to pick a threshold and the function [IM2BW](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/im2bw.html) to apply it:

```
B = im2bw(A,graythresh(A));
```

Once you do this, you can easily put the images into an M-by-N-by-100 logical matrix. Here's an example of how you could do this in a loop, assuming the variables `M` and `N` are defined:

```
allImages = false(M,N,100);  %# Initialize the matrix to store all the images
for k = 1:100
  %# Here, you would load your image into variable A
  allImages(:,:,k) = im2bw(A,graythresh(A));  %# Threshold A and add it to
                                              %#   the matrix allImages
end
```

Comment: I was going to put an answer in lolcode. I guess you have saved me some work :).